# Difference between app.use('/', router) and app.use(router)

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a node.js application and saw that some people use
`app.use('/',router)`
and some people use
`app.use(router)`
What is the difference between these two and which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference in this case.

```
app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])
```

If you call `app.use` without specifying `path` explicitly, it takes a default value which is `/`.

But using this paramaeter you can have more than a single router in your app. See examples in [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/ru/api.html#app.mountpath):

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express(); // the main app
var admin = express(); // the sub app

admin.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(admin.mountpath); // /admin
  res.send('Admin Homepage');
});

app.use('/admin', admin); // mount the sub app
```

Comment: Ah oke. So if I want to host my angular 2 website on '/' and my api on '/api' I should make 2 routers?

Comment: This may make sence.